# Link Rcpp with C code for Adaptive Metropolis rejection sampling

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp

I'd like to use Adaptive Metropolis rejection sampling(AMRS) for my Gibbs sampling. I could use the package `HI` in R directly and use the algorithm. However, since I have too many parameters, sampling one by one in a loop in R is rather slow. So I am considering writing the whole sampling part in Rcpp. The problem is how to use the AMRS function in Rcpp. One choice is find a way to use the R function in Rcpp, but it will be slow. Then I found the original C code in the page

[1]: AMRS http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~wally.gilks/adaptive.rejection/web_page/Welcome.html

So the question become how to integrate the C code with Rcpp. When I'm searching around "call C in C++", those are all about compile C first, then C++, then link. However I don't know how to do that in Rcpp since the compilation happens when I was using SourceCpp. Anyone can give me some suggestions how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out how [`HI`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HI/) implemented the [C code in their package](https://github.com/cran/HI/blob/master/src/arms-R.c).

Specifically, you should implement your own version of:

```
SEXP arms(SEXP bounds, SEXP myldens, SEXP yprev, SEXP size, SEXP rho);
```

That is given in https://github.com/cran/HI/blob/master/src/arms-R.c#L86-L172

In this case, you should opt to replace the `SEXP` object with the appropriate `Rcpp` data types for:

```
/* bounds      : boundaries of the support of the density */
/* myldens     : R function to evaluate log density */
/* yprev       : previous value from markov chain */
/* size        : number of sampled values to be obtained */
/* rho         : R environment in which the logdensity is evaluated */
```

**Note:** The implementation should really be package-based instead of using `sourceCpp()`

Comment: Yes -- Starting from a working package, and adding the skeleton components Rcpp needs (eg in DESCRIPTION, NAMESPACE, etc) should get a nicely enhanced package,  Maybe start with a simple(r) Rcpp package first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I looked into the code and your method is definitely feasible. However, I ended up with call the C headers in C++, and modified the code the apply the C function (since in C++ a void pointer need to be casted), then it worked. I will make a package later but right now I  just stick with SourceCpp....since it will take me some time to figure out how to make one. And the speed in C++ is unbelievably fast, with took 10 seconds instead more than 30 mins in R.

Comment: @JiangDu I'd love to see the solution you came up with. Please post a link in the future =)

Comment: @Coatless Yes, of course. I'll try to find a place, maybe try Rcpp gallery...but I don't know if that will qualify for a post... And I have done a little bit search about your blog, what is very good.

Comment: @JiangDu you are more than welcome to submit a post there if you want. But, definitely give the Rcpp gallery a shot!